# What's wrong with my Comparator (Hysteresis)

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis

My intention is to design a comparator to be used to sense the voltage change in the sensor. Exploring further into comparator's I got that, I must implement Hysteresis to avoid unnecessary switching and use the design in harsh environments.

Below is the circuit diagram and R5 is output change from the sensor

[image: circuit]
Here is the simulation graph:

[image: graph]

I am unable to understand the sharp fall and rise between the resistances 190K and 370K. Since I am using Hysteresis, the comparator must operate in saturation region always. What can be issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an operating point analysis (`.op`) with a sweep of the resistor value. In an operating point analysis there is no concept of time, so the comparator doesn't really know whether the input is rising or falling. To simulate this circuit you need to use a transient analysis an just vary the voltage on `in` using a piece-wise linear (PWL) voltage source.